# saving one column from a test file into an array in python

Tags: python

I have a textfile (created by a fortran program) with the following format:

```
  -12.7414170939064                1
  -11.5491412174559                2
  -9.71491476113225                3
  -7.58225748434563                4
  -7.31861308884334                5
  -6.34960810316479                6
  -4.80519553745030                7
  -3.90146854139010                8
  -3.24840468213061                9
  -3.00329610180486               10
```

Each line starts with a couple of spaces. Then comes a float. This is followed by a number of spaces, and then an integer. I want to store the first float of every line into an array of floats, and nothing else. The integer in the second column is irrelevant. How do I do this in python?

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r') #open file for reading

list_with_floats = []
for line in file:
    temp = line.split() #create a list with the float and the int as list elements
    list_with_floats.append(temp[0]) #store the float in the list

print(list_with_floats)

['-12.7414170939064', '-11.5491412174559', '-9.71491476113225', '-7.58225748434563', '-7.31861308884334', '-6.34960810316479', '-4.80519553745030', '-3.90146854139010', '-3.24840468213061', '-3.00329610180486']
```